# ECW Exception when exporting a map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping, ecw

Since monday Qgis has been unstable, everytime I try to export a map (or worse an atlas) it has crashed.

I get the folowwing message :

```
---------------------------
ECW Exception
---------------------------
(thread) ECW Version : 5,3,0,862
 Unknown Error: 
An error has occurred in this application.  If you receive this message,
please report it to Hexagon Geospatial Support to assist with fixing this error.

An Access Violation Exception occurred at code address 0x1805f79df attempting to
WRITE to memory address 0x18.

Dump: 488942f8488bc24883c4205bc3cccccccc40534883ec204533c033d233c9ff15

Stack Trace:

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I tried to contact Hexagon Geospatial without much succes. I guessed the problem was  caused by an ecw file, but most the maps didn't have one.

Comment: Do you have a Hexagon license for writing ecw files? What format did you try to export to?

Comment: No I don't the files were sent by a client so I can't do a lot about it.I tried to export my maps to pdf and jpeg.

Comment: If you use GDAL to translate the files to geotiff, and replace them in your QGIS project, does it work?